# Thread safety SingletonHolder performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, poco

In the POCO framework, the SingletonHodler is a template class for managing sigleton objects. The method which obtains the singleton object is :

```
    S* get()
    /// Returns a pointer to the singleton object
    /// hold by the SingletonHolder. The first call
    /// to get will create the singleton.
{
    FastMutex::ScopedLock lock(_m);
    if (!_pS) _pS = new S;
    return _pS;
}
```

The problem is this method always uses the mutex to ensure that there isn't more than one singleton object created in multithreaded environment. I think it is appropriate to synchronize in the first time the method called. It will waste resources if we synchronize after that. I know [Double check locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) can resolve this problem but it may be [broken](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html).

My question is whether POCO would rather ensure the safety in multithreaded environment than save resources?

Comment: Don’t use singletons and you’ll never have any problems related to singletons.

Comment: Any question regarding performance of a certain construct should always be answered with "Have you measured it for your use case?". Have you?

Answer (score 0):

Following your thoughts nothing is stopping you to use it like:

```
   MySingleton* s = mySingletonHolder.get();
   s->doSomething(); //no locking
   ...
   s->doSomething(); //no locking
```

Obviously, if you use it always like:

```
   mySingletonHolder.get()->doSomthing();
   ...
   mySingletonHolder.get()->doSomthing();
```

You will always have the lock overhead.

BTW, If your are using your singleton instance in a multi-thread scenario you should guarantee that the call to **doSomething()** is thread-safe. Doing only **mySingletonHolder.get()->doSomthing();** do not guarantee you that.